# Reload page with different QueryString

Tags: javascript

I want to reload a page using JavaScript passing different parameters in URL.

My Page name is test1.aspx, I used:

```
window.location="test1.aspx?user=abc&place=xyz";
```

It's not working!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`window.location` is an object. You need to access the `href` property on it, like this:

```
window.location.href="test1.aspx?user=abc&place=xyz";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to send dynamic value, then

```
var user = "abc";
var place = "xyz";

window.location.href = "test1.aspx?user=" + user + "&place=" + place;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.location = "path page?user=" + $("#txtuser").val();
```